# fatal error: openssl/err.h: No such file or directory - windows machine

Tags: go

I'm having a hard time solving this error that occurs while trying to implement c code inside go.

Any idea?

**The error:**

```
PS C:\Users\omer\Desktop\terraform-provider-ravendb> go test -v ./ravendb
# ravendb/utils
In file included from utils\cert_conversion.go:6:
./pfx.h:1:10: fatal error: openssl/err.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <openssl/err.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
FAIL    ravendb/ravendb [build failed]
FAIL
PS C:\Users\omer\Desktop\terraform-provider-ravendb>
```

**pfx.h**

```
#include <openssl/err.h>

void init_errors();
int get_pem_size(void * pem);
void copy_pem_to(void * pem, void * dst, int size);
void free_pem(void * pem) ;
char * pfx_to_pem(void * data, long size, char * pwd, void ** key, void ** crt);
```

Comment: Looks like you need the openssl development libraries.

Comment: @danielFarrell I added this package by `go get https://github.com/openssl/openssl` and I'm still getting this error

Comment: that's a C code error, so I would think you need the C libraries, not Go libraries.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue there are three steps that need to be done

1. Downloading OpenSSL from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
2. Make sure to set
   the env variable within PowerShell `set OpenSSLDir=C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include`
3. Make sure the relative path in the `.go` is set correcly,
   for example:
   `//#cgo CFLAGS: "-IC:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/include"`
   `//#cgo LDFLAGS: "-LC:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib" -llibcrypto`